# Invalid write when initializing an array of linked lists

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, allocation

So I have this function that allocates and initialize to `NULL` what will be an array of linked lists. I actually want this function to return an array of `NULL` pointers so that I can fill it with linked lists later.

```
static t_tokens **init_tokens_groups(size_t size)
{
    t_tokens **toks_groups;
    if (!(toks_groups = malloc(sizeof(toks_groups) * size + 1)))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    while (size + 1)
    {
        printf("size: %zu\n", size);
            toks_groups[size] = NULL;
            size--;
    }
    return (toks_groups);
}
```

It works fine, but when I'm running my program (which is a minimalist shell) into Valgrind,

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./mysh
```

I'm running into this:

```
==4914== Invalid write of size 8
==4914==    at 0x10AD6B: init_tokens_groups (tokens_split.c:39)
==4914==    by 0x10AE06: split_tokens (tokens_split.c:68)
==4914==    by 0x1093D9: prompt_loop (sh21.c:38)
==4914==    by 0x10944A: main (sh21.c:57)
==4914==  Address 0x4a508f8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4914==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4914==    by 0x10AD42: init_tokens_groups (tokens_split.c:35)
==4914==    by 0x10AE06: split_tokens (tokens_split.c:68)
==4914==    by 0x1093D9: prompt_loop (sh21.c:38)
==4914==    by 0x10944A: main (sh21.c:57)
==4914== 
==4914== Invalid write of size 8
==4914==    at 0x10AD6B: init_tokens_groups (tokens_split.c:39)
==4914==    by 0x10AE06: split_tokens (tokens_split.c:68)
==4914==    by 0x109369: dispatch (sh21.c:19)
==4914==    by 0x1093F6: prompt_loop (sh21.c:42)
==4914==    by 0x10944A: main (sh21.c:57)
==4914==  Address 0x4a509f8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4914==    at 0x483A7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4914==    by 0x10AD42: init_tokens_groups (tokens_split.c:35)
==4914==    by 0x10AE06: split_tokens (tokens_split.c:68)
==4914==    by 0x109369: dispatch (sh21.c:19)
==4914==    by 0x1093F6: prompt_loop (sh21.c:42)
==4914==    by 0x10944A: main (sh21.c:57)
```

I really don't understand where it's coming from, since I'm just initializing those pointers to `NULL` at this stage, and I have no problems or bugs (well, not that I've detected) while filling, manipulating and reading those linked lists arrays in the program. I'm assuming I'm doing something weird with the memory, but I don't see where.

Comment: `size +1` in the call to `malloc` must be `(size+1)`.

Comment: What is `toks_groups`? How is it related to `t_tokens`? While the problem mentioned by @DYZ is probably the cause of the Valgrind error, please try to create a [mcve] to show us in the future.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your loop `while (size + 1)` is very odd. Why not simply `for (size_t i = 0; i < size + 1; ++i)`, which is the most common and standard type of loops for iterating over a range of values (like array indexes).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll do in the future. Also, it's a school project and for some reasons (that I don't understand), we're not allowed to use 'for' loops.

Comment: @Zest Not allowing `for` loops seems to be one of those weird and often arbitrary restrictions that some teachers seems to like, especially when it's unrelated to the assignment itself. Anyway, a `for` look like `for (init; cond; increment) { body }` can be translated into `init; while (cond) { body; increment }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
toks_groups = malloc(sizeof(toks_groups) * size + 1))
```

is wrong, and causes a problem later the first time you do `toks_groups[size] = NULL;` (which is outside the allocated region). Valgrind tells you that the invalid write is of 8 bytes because the size of a pointer on your system is 8 bytes.

If you want to allocate `size + 1` elements you should put the expression in parentheses. The fact that you are doing `sizeof(toks_groups)` is also very strange and doesn't make much sense. What you probably wanted to do is the following:

```
toks_groups = malloc(sizeof(*toks_groups) * (size + 1)))
```

If you only want to allocate `size` elements (not `size + 1`) then remove the `+ 1` from `malloc()` and change the `while (...)` condition. You also don't really need the `while` at all, if you want to initialize everything to `NULL` you can just use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.

Also, as a rule of thumb:

1. Use meaningful names. Calling something `size` when it's clearly not a size, but just a number of elements, is confusing.
2. Use the proper code constructs. Using a `while` loop to iterate on a range of values is really counter intuitive and can easily lead to errors.

A better version of the above code would be the following:

```
static t_tokens **init_tokens_groups(size_t n)
{
    t_tokens **toks_groups;

    if (!(toks_groups = calloc(sizeof(*toks_groups) * (n + 1))))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return toks_groups;
}
```

I am still unsure whether you actually need the additional element or not, but you should know that.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Marco. The problem was indeed with the '+ 1' not in the parentheses. It's a school project and I'm only allowed to use a limited number of existing functions, and 'calloc' isn't a part of those. I'm also not allowed to use 'for' loops for some strange reasons. And I use the extra element to keep an extra NULL pointer at the end of my array, to use it as a stop when iterating it